# Java NIO - deregister client connection on server side

Tags: java, sockets, nio, channel

I am writing a simple NIO server using `Selectors` and NIO channels. Every time I have an incoming connection, I register it with the Selector using the following code:

```
// accept connection
 SocketChannel client = server.accept();
 System.out.println("Accepting connection from " + client.socket().getLocalSocketAddress());

 client.configureBlocking(false);
 client.socket().setTcpNoDelay(true);
 client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

On the client side, since I have only one socketChannel, it is easy to simply close the channel and de-register with the selector. On the erver side, however, all I'm doing is await writes from ANY client that ever connected (potentially thousands). I sthere a way to detect that the client has disconnected on the server side? It seems that the selector will get very inefficient after e.g. 10K connections, most of which would probably be dead after a short while..

Answer (score 3):

When the client disconnects, the server will get an OP_READ event for the channel, and read() will return -1. When this happens, close the channel.

NB You only have to close the channel. Cancelling the key, deregistration etc, happens automatically.

Comment: True in most cases but bad network components/bad network configurations can drop connections without sending the "connection closed" signal (I used WireShark to find that out). I had to resort to the client sending ping messages regurarly and setting a socket read time-out on the server. But this was done with plain socket I/O and a few clients, not sure how that works/can work with NIO and so many clients.

Comment: @vanOekel Certainly, but that's the answer to a different question. To detect a network outage in TCP you have to send. In this question the OP seems to think there is no notification at all, even for an orderly close by the peer.